# How many cores on this machine?

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm a bit confused about the number of cores on my Mac. I'm not entirely clear on the difference between processors, cores, and threads. If I check 'About this Mac', I see 1 processor, 2 cores. But I'm working in Node.js and if I check `os.cpus().length`, it returns 4. Why are these numbers different? Is it just because each core has 2 threads?

Comment: hyperthreading. you may have one physical core, but because of intel's marketing gurus, that one core APPEARS as two to the OS

Comment: processor = the physical chip. core = a discrete execution unit within that chip. most intel i-series chips are either two- or four-core. then there's hyperthreading, which makes a core appears as two separate cores, so a hyperthreaded cpu effectively appears as double the cores, so your average core i7 cpu will show 8 cores, even though there's only 4 actual physical ones, inside that one chip package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threads are elements of software, not hardware  They are not relevant here.  Your Mac has two cores and has support for hyper-threading.  The latter makes it appear that you have twice as many cores as you really have.

Comment: So to clarify - 1 processor (intel i5), 2 cores in that processor, each hyper-threaded, which allows the cpu to effectively function with 4 cores? So 'hyper-threading' is a hardware spec, and 'threading' is a software abstraction?

Comment: That's pretty much right.  "Hyper-threading" is an Intel brand name for the ability to simultaneously execute multiple instructions on a single core. It's a little confusingly named since it as an aspect of hardware while threads themselves are an aspect of software.  The cores can pretty much always execute threads in parallel.  The hyper-threading is more or less effective depending on various hardware and software factors, so you're not necessarily really getting the 2x performance increase in practice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading

Answer (score 1):

You have a processor with two physical cores, each one supporting *Hyper-threading* (Intel's brand, it means that they can run 2 threads at the same time), so you have "four logical cores".